# Ajax form request and html2pdf function

Tags: php, html, forms

I have AJAX form request that works perfect. I need to make a some callback to run the html2pdf function after the form is submitet, and when the form is empty not to pass. Can someone please help

here is my code

```
function sendContact() {
var valid;  
valid = validateContact();
if(valid) {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "contact_mail.php",
    data:'userName='+$("#userName").val()+'&userEmail='+$("#userEmail").val()+'&subject='+$("#subject").val()+'&content='+$(content).val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
    $("#mail-status").html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
   }


 function validateContact() {
var valid = true;   
$(".demoInputBox").css('background-color','');
$(".info").html('');

if(!$("#userName").val()) {
    $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userName").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#userEmail").val()) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#userEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#subject").val()) {
    $("#subject-info").html("(required)");
    $("#subject").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}
if(!$("#content").val()) {
    $("#content-info").html("(required)");
    $("#content").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
}

return valid;
```

}

here is my html2pdf funtion it works perfect. I  just need to merge the two functions

```
    document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const invoice = this.document.getElementById("invoice");
    console.log(invoice);
    console.log(window);
    var opt = {
        margin: 0,
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 1 },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };
    html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
})
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem then exactly...where are you stuck? Anything you want to run after Ajax has completed needs to be within (or called from code within) the "success" function.

Comment: i tried it didnt't work that way.

Comment: Update the question to show exactly what you tried please - we can't fix "didn't work". Currently your PDF is triggered by clicking on a button, so if you want it to happen when the Ajax finishes instead then you'd need to remove that event handler.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.